# Owl Carousel : From right only,start from a specific position

Tags: jquery, carousel, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

[image]

but as you can see it always take the center of a div.

what I did

```
$('#event').owlCarousel({
        loop: false,
        margin: 20,
        center:true,
        nav: false,
        dots: true,       
        responsive: {

            1000: {
                items: 4
            }
        }
    });
```

This makes the slider overflow only from right.But how can I change its starting position.

```
loop: false,center:true,
```

this css helps but make the carousel stop working.

```
.owl-stage {
        transform: translate3d(80px, 0px, 0px) !important;
    }
```

Any Help?

Comment: remove this line margin: 20 and check it

Comment: not working. as it is removing only spaces

Comment: If possible share url?

Answer (score 1):

Include screenLeft:true

```
$('#event').owlCarousel({
    screenLeft:true,
    loop: false,
    margin: 20,
    center:true,
    nav: false,
    dots: true,       
    responsive: {

        1000: {
            items: 4
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain how adding `screenLeft:true,` allows the OP to start the carousel from a specific position?